# Creating header again when printing table with multiple pages

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, printing

I've created a table in a webform using C#. I want to print only the table when the user click the print button in the webform.

I have implemented the Javascript in asp.net where only the div content printed. This works, however, as there are many rows in the table, there are many pages.

I would like to have the table header showing again in each of the new page. How can I go about doing this?

My codes:
in asp.net - print button, table

```
<asp:Button ID="printBtn" runat="server" Text="Print" onClientClick="printdiv('tableDiv')" />
            <div id="tableDiv">
            <asp:Table ID="resultsTable" runat="server" GridLines="Both">
            </asp:Table>
            </div>
```

in asp.net - javascript for printing

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function printdiv(printpage) {
            var headstr = "Header";
            var footstr = "Footer";
            var newstr = document.all.item(printpage).innerHTML;
            var oldstr = document.body.innerHTML;
            document.body.innerHTML = headstr + newstr + footstr;
            window.print();
            document.body.innerHTML = oldstr;
            return false;
        }
        </script>
```

Table method in code behind:

```
    protected void resultTable()
    {
        //database setup codes
        ...............

        try
        {
            //database query codes
            ............

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                //Set a table width.
                resultsTable.Width = Unit.Percentage(60.00);
                //Create a new row for adding a table heading.
                TableRow tableHeading = new TableRow();

                //Create and add the cells that contain the Name column heading text.
                TableHeaderCell nameHeading = new TableHeaderCell();
                nameHeading.Text = "Name";
                nameHeading.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
                tableHeading.Cells.Add(nameHeading);

                TableHeaderCell ageHeading = new TableHeaderCell();
                ageHeading.Text = "Age";
                ageHeading.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
                tableHeading.Cells.Add(ageHeading);

                resultsTable.Rows.Add(tableHeading);


                while (reader.Read())
                {

                    TableRow detailsRow = new TableRow();

                    TableCell nameCell = new TableCell();
                    nameCell.Text = reader["name"].ToString();
                    detailsRow.Cells.Add(nameCell);

                    TableCell ageCell = new TableCell();
                    ageCell.Text = reader["age"].ToString();
                    detailsRow.Cells.Add(ageCell);

                    resultsTable.Rows.Add(detailsRow);

                }
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a CSS Stylesheet with method:

```
thead { display:table-header-group }
```

However, this method only works in browser IE and Firefox.